# How to get ng-options values and fire a function when value inside changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have a sample code where I need to load the ajax data, I am making a call to a thirdparty APIS, and the url has a variable parameter inside it. The variable parameter is supposed to come from the ng-options of the select drop down, but it wont work, I am getting the value of undefined for the value when  url is constructed.

the url becomes like this:

https://thirdparty.example.pub/releases/' + value + '/measures,

however when the ajax call finishes, the url becomes

https://thirdparty.example.pub/releases/undefined/measures

Can you please guide me as to how do I change the url as and when I change the select options.

My fiddle is here, please see the console:

http://jsbin.com/nalisugaxa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The question should be self-containing - i.e. without relying on external sites like jsbin

Comment: Please add your code to the question.  Also your question is quite confusing.  Please reread and see if you can make it clearer as to what exactly you need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned the js bin:

http://jsbin.com/cuxizoduha/1/edit?html,js,console,output

The value is undefined because when you make the url, value is not assigned anything. Besides, you didn't link the select's ng-change to a controller function.

Here is the revision:

```
$scope.getValues = function(value){
theFactory.getValues(value).then(
  function(data) {
     $scope.features = data;
     console.info(data);
  });  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

'getValues' is defined as a function that takes a parameter called 'value'

```
getValues:function(value) { .... }
```

But when you make a call you the function you are not passing any 'value' (parameter is missing) hence its coming as undefined.

```
$scope.features = theFactory.getValues();
```

You have to pass the value selected from the dropdown to this function call, then it will work fine.